# How to check all stored procedures which update a specific column

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Following is the sample to search stored procedures which have the keyword `Student` in them:

```
SELECT TOP (1000) *
FROM [eUniversityManagement].[sys].[all_sql_modules]
WHERE definition LIKE '%Student%'
```

I just wondering can we search any stored procedure that has and `UPDATE` on `Student.name` for example:

```
UPDATE STUDENT 
SET Name = @Name, 
    Address = @Address, 
    DOB = @DOB 
WHERE id = @StudentID
```

Thanks.

Comment: `WHERE definition LIKE '%update student%' AND definition LIKE '%Name=%'`` - you need to cover all combinations of spaces and schemas though, and you could still miss some.

Comment: use regex for this

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-sql-referenced-entities-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) function for this. It's a little complicated, as it wants the procedure name which references the column, so you need to start off with all objects and apply the functions

```sql
SELECT o.name, schema_name = s.name
FROM sys.objects o
JOIN sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = o.schema_id
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities (QUOTENAME(s.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(o.name), 'OBJECT') r
WHERE o.type IN ('P', 'TR')
  AND r.referenced_entity_name = 'student'
  AND r.referenced_minor_name = 'Name'
  AND r.is_updated = 1;
```